# what is if statement used for when followed by element's index in an array?

Tags: python

What is (if) used for when it is not followed by comparison or logical operators?
I mean this line `if magic_square[newi , newj]:` in the following code

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
magic_square = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=int)
n = 1
i, j = 0, N//2 
while n <= N**2: 
 magic_square[i, j] = n 
 n += 1 
 newi , newj = (i - 1) % N, (j + 1)% N 
 if magic_square[newi , newj]:
  i += 1 
 else:
  i, j = newi , newj
print(magic_square)
```

Comment: It treats anything that doesn't have a comparison as if it has `== True` after it.

Comment: @verumIgnis Not quite. `if [1]:` is quite different from `if [1] == True`.

Comment: It is more accurate to say that `if x:` is equivalent to `if bool(x) == True:`... Or using your words: *"It treats anything that doesn't have a comparison as if it has == True after converting it to `bool`."*

Comment: Yes should have specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement will evaluate the result of the expression `magic_square[newi, newj]` for "truthy"-ness. In python, a value will evaluate to as true in a boolean context when it is

- True
- A non-empty collection
- A numeric non-zero value
- An object who's class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method which doesn't return the bool value `False` or integer `0` respectively.

In this case, if `magic_square` is a 2-dimensional array of numbers, the if statement is equivalent to `if magic_square[newi, newj] != 0`

Comment: `None` and `0` are objects, but they are not truthy.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/6045800) (and the rest on that page) explains this much better (no offence)... Instead of repeating the same answers, maybe it is better to close as a duplicate (seeing you have over 3k rep)

Comment: The *default* truthiness for an object (inherted from `object`) is `True` unless the type overrides `__bool__` (or `__len__`) to provide a different value.

Comment: I have edited the answer to be more accurate